# Vega-Lite - How to Combine Line and Symbol Legend

Tags: javascript, json, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I am able to implement vega-lite chart which renders as follows:

[image]

The code for it looks something like this:

```
{
  "width": 400,
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 600, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {"name": "data-eb6aa7311f370dcc2f64d37c32c9e387"},
  "usermeta": {"embedOptions": {"renderer": "svg"}},
  "layer":[
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 0.2}},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", 
              "type": "nominal",
              "axis": { "title": "Quizzes"}
             },
        "y": {"field": "my-score", 
              "type": "quantitative",
              "axis": { "title": "Percentage Score"}
             }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "red"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "max", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "color": "red", "size":100, "opacity": "100"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "max", "type": "quantitative"},
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "#02c754"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "avg", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "color": "#02c754", "size":100, "opacity": "100"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "avg", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "#02b6de"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "min", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "color": "#02b6de", "size":100, "opacity": "100"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal"},
        "y": {"field": "min", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
    
  ],
  "title": "Quiz Scores",
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.17.0.json",
  "datasets": {
    "data-eb6aa7311f370dcc2f64d37c32c9e387": [ 
      {
        "title": "Quiz-1",
        "my-score": 62,
        "max": 80,
        "avg": 45,
        "min": 15
      },
      {
        "title": "Quiz-2",
        "my-score": 48,
        "max": 48,
        "avg": 30,
        "min": 10
      },
      {
        "title": "Quiz-3",
        "my-score": 54,
        "max": 62,
        "avg": 36,
        "min": 12
      },
      {
        "title": "Quiz-4",
        "my-score": 27,
        "max": 69,
        "avg": 50,
        "min": 9
      },
      {
        "title": "Quiz-5",
        "my-score": 40,
        "max": 48,
        "avg": 30,
        "min": 11
      },
      {
        "title": "Quiz-6",
        "my-score": 50,
        "max": 55,
        "avg": 28,
        "min": 5
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to render legends for the same something like this:

[image]

I am not able to figure out how I can do this. I checked the example given [here](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/line.html) or precisely [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AGVMbKAGsABDk1Q1ZtgDMzYswBU4sMwGE2CHElk0bNlJ1FxoEOEpFFSRMFFRQBnVBNGjYziNTCEooCGIQAF8lQSQATzh1NABtUGR1ExThWTgouFkoNmUaWTI0UAAPXpAdcIBVf0xBhnGUsqQKwpA7AMFlFOUY5qVMEpxm9ExEHDZ1JGSFksGkMjJ1PgOU8L8opbgVlMsaayjt3ZSARwYfh0sR0pAKSnagmOgxeb3QEBKCCYbGSWx2exAsm8XVOBXyhRqc3q8SG6PebC6EyUbF8UDoF1QAEYlEtBII4KtUJh1Aw4AtWu1Ot1BgMScM4GM6JNpuhZvMWctOalNqTfvtDsdcedLtdbhR7uhHvIFa8lR8vmi1SAAUC6DEaGCFpDoSTYUqEUiUd8yegsQgcWd8QBdfJAA) example. But the [stock data used by this example](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite-v1/blob/master/data/stocks.csv) has different schema: `{symbol, date, price}` and it renders different colors for different values in symbol. And vega-lite seem to auto generate legends from this schema. But, in my case, the schema is of the form `{title, my-score, max, avg, min}`. How do I implement legends as shown in the picture above (also note that legend for bar chart is somewhat wide)? I am fine to have somewhat different legends as long as they are sensible. But do I have to transform data to match the schema to what vega-lite stocks example schema?

PS: You can try out my visualization at [this URL](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-Pwgq9IuMAGJUKE7ABWZDxjb4LY7egK4v6854j0Z525rVDosgEvGDS1cvo83Vq029kYTmOnkVyNu2dCjujbu9gf+wNIWNYMMRqPGWNDxNjvYTldTlUzok0Q1PMXiXVNlXeDcsy3KtLQJOs1EPRs5wrFs229Lse2sCoPxHaUv3lcD00zFD0QXfMwL1NM4WYTdjG3ODa1tRD7S5J0T1dd10MvEBr2wokAzBB8Q2fSNBjfdBcNHWVxyI6dLkA+dNQonU5MNWjoPo2C8V3BCAF0bgAgEgWBZlWWKLAABIkTgDIdFGOQYDyDhEAAelcwkSA0ZYSDxOAWEsZYIFwVybLsjzqC8sx+RgagPOQZZHDsZYVgAKw4Ag3lMDQOGoGBSRMLQNAsaxbAcZxXHcTwfD8AIghCcJIhiJBOgzIzRkBEEzEcN54URVkBG8LAy0QKJMEg3ZkD7YbaMQRw+xY1UOpMsxvF6hEkRFEZkCiYaPiQHasHXXYlBm-BhMW9qQE64EzAUdb+q2pABz2hV+CGibFH4M6HzWA82oU4yusHYaNoGxBvDsV6BDCI6N0QPtxrzJAwkuwHlq6vsHs2lEUCR-aUF2z7EFO+1ZucNG-gx27+Gx8HEehhHpuJ7wieRhHlD01QgA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

```
{
  "width": 400,
  "config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 600, "continuousHeight": 300}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"title": "Quiz-1", "my-score": 62, "max": 80, "avg": 45, "min": 15},
      {"title": "Quiz-2", "my-score": 48, "max": 48, "avg": 30, "min": 10},
      {"title": "Quiz-3", "my-score": 54, "max": 62, "avg": 36, "min": 12},
      {"title": "Quiz-4", "my-score": 27, "max": 69, "avg": 50, "min": 9},
      {"title": "Quiz-5", "my-score": 40, "max": 48, "avg": 30, "min": 11},
      {"title": "Quiz-6", "my-score": 50, "max": 55, "avg": 28, "min": 5}
    ]
  },
  "transform": [{"fold": ["max", "avg", "min", "my-score"]}],
  "usermeta": {"embedOptions": {"renderer": "svg"}},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "title", "type": "nominal", "axis": {"title": "Quizzes"}}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 0.2}},
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.key == 'my-score' "}],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "value",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "Percentage Score"}
        },
        "color": {"field": "key", "scale": {"range": ["#312eaa"]}}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "line"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum.key == 'max' || datum.key == 'min' ||datum.key == 'avg'  "
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "stroke": {
          "field": "key",
          "scale": {"range": ["green", "red", "#3aa1ff"]},
          "legend": {"title": ""}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": "datum.key == 'max' || datum.key == 'min' ||datum.key == 'avg'  "
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
        "fill": {
          "field": "key",
          "scale": {"range": ["green", "red", "#3aa1ff"]},
          "legend": null
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Quiz Scores",
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.6.json"
}
```

Comment: Am not as proficient as you in vega-lite. Please help me understand what you did: **Q1.** filtering three `key`s for line mark and specifying `value` as field is enough for vega-lite to plot three lines? Till now I was explicitly specifying field to be used for specific line. But this approach seem different. Is there any article in vega lite doc that exaplains this approach? **Q2.** Why it still show `my-score` legend even when there is no legend specified for bar? Also what does it mean by `"legend": {"title": ""}` and `"legend": null`?

Comment: Your original had lots of repeated encodings which are not necessary. Your data was also in the wrong shape which is what the fold transform takes care of - have a look in the editor at the table it generates. That is the answer to question 1 and question 2. If you put a title in the title, you can see what happens and if you remove legend null, you'll end up with 2 legends. Have a play with the spec to see what changes. Plotting in Vega usually comes down to how your data is shaped and the key to both questions is the fold transform.

Comment: Ohh I see, so `color` encoding by default creates a legend. To remove redundant legends, you set `"legend": null` & to remove redundant title `key`, u set `"legend": {"title": ""}`. Also, I had some redundant encoding because thats how I found some examples in docs: creating encodings and then layering them up. Is there any book / course from which you got grip of vega-lite? Or examples, tutorial and doc at [vega-lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/) & [this course](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/data-visualization-curriculum) are the only sources? Is there any better source you referred?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any courses - I just learnt by going through all the examples. If you get stuck, just post here. You can see my LinkedIn for some advanced dataviz examples and I post all the code in my Github for others to learn from.

Comment: Btw, it seems that this approach makes it impossible to apply on-hover animation to just one circle (say just max). Instead of animating just one hovered-circle, it animates all three circles. Also specifying `"tooltip": [{"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"}]`, just shows `value: N` for all circles, but not `Avg: N`, `Max: N`and `Min: N`. Is there any way to fix it. [Here is my viz](https://pastebin.com/Jinrncwq). (I have shared URL on pastebin as vega URL is huge for comments and stckoverflow comments does not allow shortened URLs.) Should I create new question for doubt?

Comment: (continued from last comment...) I noticed a weird behavior, when we open the bitly link shared in pastebin, the circles in visualisation are not rendered in edge browser, but are present in chrome and brave browser.

Comment: I'd add a new question describing your desired behaviour.

Comment: Asked new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767964/achieving-custom-tooltip-containing-multiple-columns-in-vega-lite).